# Plotting Image with Plotly in Django

Tags: django, plotly-python

Hi community maybe you can help me. The last couple of days I was trying to find a solution to plot an image in Django with plotly because I need a 2nd trace with a scatter on top of it and additional a slider wo move around. But first things first. In order to plot an image from an URL I've put in the following in views.py in my Django app

views.py

```
from skimage import io

def slide_plot(centroid=1):
#steps = Ypixels.objects.filter(centroid__in=[centroid]).order_by('step').values_list('step', falt=True).distinct()

#CentroidCount.objects.filter(centroid__in=[centroid]).order_by('id_observation').values_list('id_observation', flat=True).distinct()
url = 'https://www.cs.technik.fhnw.ch/iris/sji_png/images/20140910_112825_3860259453/20140910_112825_3860259453_1400_1176.jpg'
img_array = io.imread(url)

image = go.Image(
                source=url
)

layout = go.Layout(
                title='Appearances for Centroids', 
                xaxis=dict(
                    title='Step',
                ),
                paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                
                yaxis={
                    'title':'occurences'
                    },
                )

data = [image]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_test = plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')

return plot_test
```

once this is resolved I can move to the next step creating the scatter trace.
Any help would be appreciated